# Declare a pointer to pointer inside C# struct

Tags: c#, pointers, struct, double

How to convert this c++ struct into C# equivalent?

```
typedef struct readdirplus_hash_bucket {
     ifs_rdplusbucket **hash;
     int hash_size;
} ifs_rdplushashbucket;
```

I stuck in double pointer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to pass this struct to unmanaged code using p/invoke, or are you trying to rewrite some code in C#? What does the pointer to pointer mean; is it a pointer to an array, an array of pointers, ...?

Comment: Yes, I have to pass this struct to unmanaged code. ifs_rdplusbucket itself is a struct.

Comment: You need to post native C code which shows, how this structure is used. Without these additional details, the only thing that I can say is: hash variable must have IntPtr type, use Marshal.PtrToStructure method to convert it to ifs_rdplusbucket.

Comment: Have you declared the c# equivalent of `ifs_rdplusbucket`?

Comment: Yes. ifs_rdplusbucket is declared. In case of it was a pointer, I would just declare it as "public IntPtr hash" and convert it back to ifs_rdplusbucket using Marshal.PtrToStructure. But, I am concerned about double pointer, where it is not allowed to use out or ref keyword when declaring a struct.

Comment: Double pointer is also IntPtr. Possibly it points to another IntPtr, which points to ifs_rdplusbucket. Use Marhal.ReadIntPtr and then Marshal.PtrToStructure to dereference IntPtr twice.